# Zip 3 lists of equal length

Tags: kotlin

Is there a standard operation in Kotlin stdlib which would allow to iterate over a zip of 3 (or more) lists?

Effectively it should do:

```
list1.zip(list2).zip(list3) { (a, b), c -> listOf(a, b, c)}
```

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you asked for but there is the ``mapIndexed`` function: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html. When the number of lists to zip get large, the nested zipping will result in nested pairs and it will probably get hard to read with all the brackets. But with ``mapIndexed``, you won't have this nesting issue.

Answer (score 21):

Here are functions in the style of the standard library that do this. I'm not saying these are particularly optimized, but I think they're at least easy to understand.

```
/**
 * Returns a list of lists, each built from elements of all lists with the same indexes.
 * Output has length of shortest input list.
 */
public inline fun <T> zip(vararg lists: List<T>): List<List<T>> {
    return zip(*lists, transform = { it })
}

/**
 * Returns a list of values built from elements of all lists with same indexes using provided [transform].
 * Output has length of shortest input list.
 */
public inline fun <T, V> zip(vararg lists: List<T>, transform: (List<T>) -> V): List<V> {
    val minSize = lists.map(List<T>::size).min() ?: return emptyList()
    val list = ArrayList<V>(minSize)

    val iterators = lists.map { it.iterator() }
    var i = 0
    while (i < minSize) {
        list.add(transform(iterators.map { it.next() }))
        i++
    }

    return list
}
```

Usage:

```
val list1 = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val list2 = listOf(5, 6)
val list3 = listOf(7, 8, 9)

println(zip(list1, list2, list3)) // [[1, 5, 7], [2, 6, 8]]
```