# Mapping arrays to list of objects kotlin

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, mapping

I'm wondering about methods of mapping multiple arrays into one list of object.

I mean e.g. I have

```
val a = arrayOf("A1","A2","A3")
val b = arrayOf("B1","B2","B3")
```

and

```
data class SomeClass(val v1:String, val v2:String)
```

I want to parse it in elegant way to have list like that:

```
val list = listOf(SomeClass("A1","B1"),SomeClass("A2","B2"),SomeClass("A3","B3"))
```

I assume they are of the same length. The only way I thought of is:

```
val list = mutableListOf<SomeClass>() 
for (i in a.indices) 
            array.add(SomeClass(a[i],b[i])
```

Is there a better, more elegant solution (maybe using Collecions.zip or Array.map)?

Comment: I would go for both `zip` and `map`... Note that your variant has a flaw.. if there are more elements in `a` you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [`Array.zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) and then `map`:

```
val list = a.zip(b)
            .map { SomeClass(it.first, it.second) }
```

or if you like it more:

```
val list = a.zip(b)
            .map { (a, b) -> SomeClass(a, b) }
```

Note that if both arrays differ in size, the additional values are ignored. Note also that this will create intermediate `Pair`s (which is the default transformation function of `zip`). Even though I like the explicit `map` more, @hotkeys solution regarding the overloaded method is more appropriate (you spare that hidden `Pair`-transformation):

```
val list = a.zip(b) { a, b -> SomeClass(a, b) }
```

And where the overloaded method probably shines, is when using references instead:

```
a.zip(b, ::SomeClass)
```

Which will work as long as you have a constructor matching the zipped arguments and doesn't work out of the box for the `Pair` (yet?).

Answer (score 4):

Improving on [@Roland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51766525/2196460), you can use the [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) overload that accepts a two-argument function for mapping the pairs immediately:

```
val result = a.zip(b) { x, y -> SomeClass(x, y) }
```

Comment: And how to do that if I have arrays a,b,c and want to do something like that
    
     `val result = a.zip(b,c) { x,y,z -> SomeClass(x,y,z)}`

Comment: You could do something like `a.zip(b).zip(c) { ab, c -> SomeClass(ab.first, ab.second, c) }`, but as you see that doesn't get nice. You probably should rather supply your own mapping/zipping function...

Answer (score 0):

You can write some custom fun like this:

```
inline fun <T, R, E, V> Iterable<T>.zipThree(other1: Iterable<R>, other2: Iterable<E>, transform: (T, R, E) -> V): List<V> {
        val first = iterator()
        val second = other1.iterator()
        val third = other2.iterator()
        val list = ArrayList<V>()
        while (first.hasNext() && second.hasNext()) {
            list.add(transform(first.next(), second.next(), third.next()))
        }
        return list
    }
```

And use this transform for getting List

```
val strings = listOf("1", "2")
        val ints = listOf(1, 2)
        val boolean = listOf(true, false)

        val listYoutObjects = strings.zipThree(ints, boolean) { one, two, three -> YouObject(one, two, three) }
```

Comment: be sure to also check for `third.hasNext()` in the `while`-condition. Note, that what you did here was not really asked in this question, however there is one, were your answer fits: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50078266/6202869