# How to store the data in a list from 2 for loops?

Tags: android, azure, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

So... I am trying to store data into a list from 2 different for loops. The reason being I am retrieving data from 2 different tables as there is no implementation of joining of tables yet in the Azure-Android SDK.

Currently, I have,

```
for(results in tableOne) {
    val banana: String = results.asJsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("fruit").asString
}

for(results in tableTwo) {
        val yellow: String = results.asJsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("color").asString
    }
```

I have created a class called "Fruits" which gets and set that I am gonna implement them when creating the list

So something like `fruitList.add(Fruits("banana", "color"))`

So any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` to change one type of list into another. Combining the results of two lists into a new single list is done with `zip`. So you can map the JSON results lists to  String lists, and then combine them.

```
val fruitTypes = tableOne.map { it.asJsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("fruit").asString }
val colors = tableTwo.map { it.asJsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("color").asString }
val fruits = fruitTypes.zip(colors) { fruitType, color -> Fruit(fruitType, color) }
```

Edit: You could do this a little more efficiently in one step:

```
val fruits = tableOne.zip(tableTwo) { fruitTypeJson, colorJson -> 
    val fruitType = fruitTypeJson.asJsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("fruit").asString
    val color = colorJson .asJsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("color").asString
    Fruit(fruitType, color) 
}
```

Comment: So I can replace my for loop with map and it will still iterate through the query?

Comment: Yes, assuming `tableOne` is a List. The lambda you pass to the map function is called on each element of the collection to create a new List.

Comment: Sorry for taking up your time. However, if I have, for example, I have more than 2 maps (including "weight" and "volume"), can I still zip them up together and combine those lists?

Comment: There aren't built-in functions for zipping multiple lists at once. Someone asked that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078266/zip-3-lists-of-equal-length