# How to create a list from specific indexes in list of lists in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, data-science

I would like to retrieve a list, containing all elements at a specific index from list of lists in Kotlin, for example:

```
List1 = [a,b,c,e]
List2 = [1,2,3,4]
List3 = [!,@,#,$]

Input = [List1,List2,List3]
Index = 2

Desired output: [c,3,#]
```

How do I do it **efficiently** in Kotlin? Is there a better way than looping through the lists?
Thanks

Comment: This example is invalid. Arrays/lists are 0-indexed, so `Index=3` should result with: `[e,4,$]`.

Comment: This does what you want, and it also keeps information about each type [Zip 3 lists of equal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078266/zip-3-lists-of-equal-length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Input.map { it[Index] }
```

It iterates through all sublists and takes `Index` element from each of them.

Note that by creating a list of lists you lose information about the type of each sublist. You would need to redesign your data structure to keep this information.